# symfony get scalar result and entity result

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I'm using symfony 3, and im trying to `createNativeQuery` to retrieave a list of product(Entity) and the quantity (Integer) here is my function:

```
public function findStockbyStore(Store $store)
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult(Product::class, 'p');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'product_id', 'id');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('quantity', 'quantity');
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery(
      "SELECT `product_id`, `quantity` as 'quantity' FROM `stock`",
      $rsm
    );

//$query->setParameter(1, $store->getId());

return $query->getResult();
```

}

But this query only return an array of products, and if i remove the `$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'product_id', 'id');` i get an array with only the quantity.

Now instead of `$query->getResult();` i use `$query->getArrayResult();` i get an array containing the id and quantity only.

So how can i get both the Entity and the scalar object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. Doctrine is all about object.

Either you are in an object context in which case you would need a quantity attribute (for example) in your model or you are in a non-object context in which case you have the array.